# Google share link not saw in all asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, .net

I put the Google+ Share in my web site thru a txt file. Means pages (thru a javascript) reads the txt file and then put it in a certain place.
Everything goes well in my Default.aspx page.
When I want to surf in other pages (like "products") I see all the links (which they works fine, but the Google+ share is not sawing.
I really don't know if my question expressed right, that's why I'm giving the web site http://www.panos-oliveoil.gr, for anyone wants to see from first hand.
I also put the google+ line:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
```

Separately in my "products.aspx"page and is NOT working as well.

The script I use is:

```
  <div id="usefulliks"  style="text-align:left; color:Black;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var doc = "useful_links.txt";
  var path = "../pages/announce/";
  var finallinks;
  var txtLinksFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  txtLinksFile.open("GET", path + doc, true);
  txtLinksFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (txtLinksFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
  if (txtLinksFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
  finallinks = txtLinksFile.responseText.split("\n");
  document.getElementById("usefulliks").innerHTML = finallinks;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
  txtLinksFile.send();
  </script>
  </div>
```

That script works fine for other files as well like "company_announce" in all pages.
and also it works fine in that particular txt file (regarding the other links). 
I really can't understand what is the error on it.
I say that because I'm not some specialist in javascript; in fact I'm a new learner.

Finally I discover that the Google+

```
<div id="Div1" xml:lang="en" runat="server" class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
```

Works ONLY when the Default.aspx page is active...
Is there anyone knows why is that?

Comment: @CoDe aDDict. I add some details in my question. And I really can't see the photo. Difficult to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally is that... The Google+ works ONLY when the Default.aspx is ACTIVE and not in any other page.
I put it on my Footer in Master page and it works ONLY when the Default page is active....

Answer (score 2):

you have script errors on page. you can see it in firebug. get rid of those errors. these errors stop google+ button to render as button is rendered through script . see the image

[image]

Comment: Why that happen only in pages which they are in depth from root directory. And not happen in root (Default.aspx)

Comment: probably the error occurs on the home page after the creation of the button

Comment: I rem the script from Default (so it's not run) and the problem stays in the other pages

Comment: Now I see what is going on. In Default page the line (which comes from the txt file) <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div> works (interacts) with Google+. In the Other pages the same line stays as a text line and not interact.

Comment: So I take it from the TXT file and put it in the same place in "products"page and again stays as a text line!! I forgot to say (I don't know if that is important) this line always gives me an error: Attribute in "data-action" is not a valid attribute on 'element'div